# Вывод названий файлов из директории

Tags: c++

Не работает вывод имен файлов из директории

Попробовал `

```
int main() {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    hf = FindFirstFile(L"C:/MainProject/*", &FindFileData);
    if (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;
        } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: видимо пытаетесь выводить в cout wchar_t

Answer (score 2):

WinAPI функции есть в 2х вариантах: Ansi, к примеру `FindFirstFileA` и Unicode, к примеру `FindFirstFileW`

Когда вы вызываете `FindFirstFile` и указываете L"C:/MainProject/*", т.е. unicode-строку, то выбирается вариант unicode-функций, структур и т.д.

Т.е. `FindFileData.cFileName` - это unicode, и для ее отображения нужна функция `std::wcout`, а не `std::cout`

Т.е. ваш код должен быть:

```
int main() {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    hf = FindFirstFile(L"C:/MainProject/*", &FindFileData);
    if (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            std::wcout << FindFileData.cFileName << std::endl;
        } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::wcout` - это предопределённый объект `std::wostream`, а не функция

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAxWzvaTKvwV92
Чет пошло не по плану.Первым сочло какие то точки,а далее вообще двухзначные числа....Странная дичь

Comment: @Mensch, это не дичь ;) А подкаталог и каталог.

Comment: @Mensch, всегда при поиске файлов в папке находятся ".." и "." - просто игнорируйте их